# Can we install pygame package with enthought canopy?

Tags: python, pygame, canopy

I am planning to use canopy editor for my python coding, especially for some basic game development...

Could anyone please let me know if we can install pygame package for canopy editor ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install every package into your python dist. pygame might not be in the canopy package manager but even then you can install it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a knowledge base article explaining how to install external packages into Enthought Canopy: http://bit.ly/14zIgeJ

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a 32 bit version of Python. PyGame doesn't run on the 64 bit builds, and OSX ships with a 64 bit build.
download from here [python2.7.3](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3-macosx10.3.dmg)
then download [pygames](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg)